# Install x86 virtualization sokution installed AND DKMS: install completed but still cannot download driver how can I fix?

Tags: drivers, downloads

I found the option that I could install DKMS then try driver download again.
Still not able to select and apply. Please assist!

Comment: Can you add some more background information please, such as what you are using, what driver you wanted to install, and what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: The driver update is part of the additional drivers used to allow printer sharing from the host computer windows 8.1 to my virtual Ubuntu 16.04 machine. The additional drivers option will not allow selection of the x86 virtualization solution - 11. How can I get the installer update to let me select it; could it be that its not available?